# os.walk with regex

Tags: python, regex, os.walk

I'd like to get a list of files that apply to a regex that i have. I guess i should use os.walk, but how can i use it with regex?

Thanks.

Comment: Please post some code that you tried to use.  Please post your proposed solution including any error messages you're getting.  This isn't `www.do-my-job-for-me.com`

Answer (score 8):

I'm not aware of anything in the stdlib implementing this, but it is not hard to code:

```
import os, os.path

def iter_matching(dirpath, regexp):
    """Generator yielding all files under `dirpath` whose absolute path
       matches the regular expression `regexp`.
       Usage:

           >>> for filename in iter_matching('/', r'/home.*\.bak'):
           ....    # do something
    """
    for dir_, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(dirpath):
        for filename in filenames:
            abspath = os.path.join(dir_, filename)
            if regexp.match(abspath):
                yield abspath
```

Or the more general:

```
import os, os.path

def filter_filenames(dirpath, predicate):
    """Usage:

           >>> for filename in filter_filenames('/', re.compile(r'/home.*\.bak').match):
           ....    # do something
    """
    for dir_, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(dirpath):
        for filename in filenames:
            abspath = os.path.join(dir_, filename)
            if predicate(abspath):
                yield abspath
```

Answer (score 5):

If your regex can be translated into a shell expression such as `foo/*.txt` then you can use [`glob`](http://docs.python.org/library/glob.html).

```
>>> import glob
>>> glob.glob('./[0-9].*')
['./1.gif', './2.txt']
>>> glob.glob('*.gif')
['1.gif', 'card.gif']
>>> glob.glob('?.gif')
['1.gif']
```

Comment: Is glob faster than os.walk + regex?