# Python equivalent of find2perl

Tags: python, find, os.walk

Perl has a lovely little utility called [find2perl](http://www.ayni.com/perldoc/find2perl.html) that will translate (quite faithfully) a command line for the Unix `find` utility into a Perl script to do the same.

If you have a [find](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/find.html) command like this:

```
find /usr -xdev -type d -name '*share'

                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^  => name with shell expansion of '*share'
                 ^^^^ => Directory (not a file)
           ^^^ => Do not go to external file systems
     ^^^ => the /usr directory (could be multiple directories
```

It finds all the directories ending in `share` below `/usr`

Now run `find2perl /usr -xdev -type d -name '*share'` and it will emit a Perl script to do the same. You can then modify the script to your use.

Python has `os.walk()` which certainly has the needed functionality, recursive directory listing, but there are big differences.

Take the simple case of `find . -type f -print` to find and print all files under the current directory. A naïve implementation using `os.walk()` would be:

```
for path, dirs, files in os.walk(root):
    if files:
        for file in files:
            print os.path.join(path,file)
```

However, this will produce different results than typing `find . -type f -print` in the shell.

I have also been testing various os.walk() loops against:

```
# create pipe to 'find' with the commands with arg of 'root'
find_cmd='find %s -type f' % root
args=shlex.split(find_cmd)
p=subprocess.Popen(args,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
out,err=p.communicate()    
out=out.rstrip()            # remove terminating \n
for line in out.splitlines()
   print line
```

The difference is that os.walk() counts links as files; find skips these.

So a correct implementation that is the same as `file . -type f -print` becomes:

```
for path, dirs, files in os.walk(root):
    if files:
        for file in files:
            p=os.path.join(path,file)
            if os.path.isfile(p) and not os.path.islink(p):
                 print(p)
```

Since there are hundreds of permutations of find primaries and different side effects, this becomes time consuming to test every variant. Since `find` is the gold standard in the POSIX world on how to count files in a tree, doing it the same way in Python is important to me.

So is there an equivalent of `find2perl` that can be used for Python? So far I have just been using `find2perl` and then manually translating the Perl code. This is hard because the Perl file test operators are [different](http://blog.endpoint.com/2009/08/file-test-comparison-table-for-shell.html) than the Python file tests in os.path at times.

Comment: I'd suggest part of the answer could be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4639506/os-walk-with-regex Sorry I don't know find/find2perl enough to help more. *(maybe also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5141437/filtering-os-walk-dirs-and-files)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of observations and several pieces of code to help you on your way.

First, Python can execute code in this form just like Perl:

```
 cat code.py | python | the rest of the pipe story...
```

`find2perl` is a clever code template that emits a Perl function based on a template of find. Therefor, replicate this template and you will not have the "hundreds of permutations" that you are perceiving.

Second, the results from `find2perl` are not *perfect* just as there are potentially differences between versions of find, such as GNU or BSD.

Third, by default, `os.walk` is bottom up; `find` is top down. This makes for different results if your underlying directory tree is changing while you recurse it.

There are two projects in Python that may help you: [twander](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/twander/3.231) and [dupfinder](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/dupfinder/1.4.3). Each strives to be os independent and each recurses the file system like `find`.

If you template a general `find` like function in Python, set `os.walk` to recurse top down, use glob to replicate shell expansion, and use some of the code that you find in those two projects, you can replicate `find2perl` without too much difficulty.

Sorry I could not point to something ready to go for your needs...

Answer (score 4):

If you're trying to reimplement all of `find`, then yes, your code is going to get hairy.  `find` is pretty hairy all by itself.

In most cases, though, you're not trying to replicate the complete behavior of find; you're performing a much simpler task (e.g., "find all files that end in .txt").  If you really need all of `find`, just run `find` and read the output.  As you say, it's the gold standard; you might as well just use it.

I often write code that reads paths on `stdin` just so I can do this:

```
find ...a bunch of filters... | my_python_code.py
```

Comment: This only works on the assumption that your target program environment is on Unix tho. The beauty of `find2perl` is that you can write something on Unix and run it anywhere that Perl runs -- on Windows for example.

Answer (score 1):

I think [glob](http://docs.python.org/library/glob.html) could help in your implementation of this.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a Python script to use `os.walk()` to search-and-replace; it might be a useful thing to look at before writing something like this.

[Replace strings in files by Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1597649/replace-strings-in-files-by-python/1597755#1597755)

And any Python replacement for find(1) is going to rely heavily on `os.stat()` to check various properties of the file.  For example, there are flags to find(1) that check the size of the file or the last modified timestamp.